# Cannot get photos from album using facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the photos from album using the album id but cannot get it,

I'm using graph api explorer to check the URL and its not working,

First, I'm doing a `/me/albums` to get the albums,

part of result result:

```
name": "Moribay Photos",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=388544751194190&id=100001160043714&aid=79115",
      "cover_photo": "388544754527523",
```

now that i know that it has an id of `79115`, i do a `/79115/photos` and getting the following though I have 3 photos in it

```
    {
      "data": [
      ]

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong id, use `fbid` not `aid`.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/388544751194190?fields=photos
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/388544751194190/photos
```

Comment: with your URL, i may get all photos for the provided userid but i need  all photos from a particular album given the album id

Comment: It is the id of an album `"id": "388544751194190", "type": "album", "name": "Moribay Photos"`

Answer (score 2):

I know a little bit late but:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[album-id]/photos?fields=id,images,link (etc.)
```

This url gives an existing fb album photos from album-id.

Cheers.